# Sed to extract text between two strings

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

Please help me in using sed.
I have a file like below.

```
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=B
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=C
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=D
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
```

I want to get the text between START=A, END. 
I used the below query.

```
sed '/^START=A/, / ^END/!d' input_file
```

The problem here is , 
I am getting

```
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
START=D
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
```

instead of

```
START=A
  xxxxx
  xxxxx
END
```

Sed finds greedily.

Please help me in resolvng this.

Thanks in advance.

Can I use AWK for achieving above?

Comment: The other common FAQ is "from a line containing two tokens, how do I extract the text between them"; this is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
sed -n '/^START=A$/,/^END$/p' data
```

The `-n` option means don't print by default; then the script says 'do print between the line containing `START=A` and the next `END`.

You can also do it with `awk`:

> A pattern may consist of two patterns separated by a comma; in this case, the action is performed for
>          all lines from an occurrence of the first pattern though an occurrence of the second.

(from `man awk` on Mac OS X).

```
awk '/^START=A$/,/^END$/ { print }' data
```

Given a modified form of the data file in the question:

```
START=A
  xxx01
  xxx02
END
START=A
  xxx03
  xxx04
END
START=A
  xxx05
  xxx06
END
START=B
  xxx07
  xxx08
END
START=A
  xxx09
  xxx10
END
START=C
  xxx11
  xxx12
END
START=A
  xxx13
  xxx14
END
START=D
  xxx15
  xxx16
END
```

The output using GNU `sed` or Mac OS X (BSD) `sed`, and using GNU `awk` or BSD `awk`, is the same:

```
START=A
  xxx01
  xxx02
END
START=A
  xxx03
  xxx04
END
START=A
  xxx05
  xxx06
END
START=A
  xxx09
  xxx10
END
START=A
  xxx13
  xxx14
END
```

Note how I modified the data file so it is easier to see where the various blocks of data printed came from in the file.

If you have a different output requirement (such as 'only the first block between START=A and END', or 'only the last ...'), then you need to articulate that more clearly in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need text between START=A and the next END,  the above one gives data between START=A and last END. Hope you got my prob.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Both the `awk` and the `sed` scripts — at least on my machine with my copy of the data file you provided — print 5 blocks of data between `START=A` and `END`, and the blocks with `START=B` to `END`, `START=C` to `END` and `START=D` to `END` are all omitted from the output.  Which platform are you testing on?  Which version of `sed` are you using?  Which version of `awk` are you using? (I note that your test data repeats verbatim the blocks between `START=A` and `END`. It would be much better if you had different lines in between so you could see which lines are being printed.)

Comment: When I test this, the start and end toeks are included in the output, while I had the impression the OP wanted only data BETWEEN them.

Comment: @LennartRolland: The sample desired output specifically includes the `START=A` and `END` lines.  If you don't want the start and end markers to appear, you can use `sed` like this: `sed -n -e '/^START=A$/,/^END$/ { /^START=A$/d; /^END$/d; p; }'`.  Or, you can use `awk` like this: `awk '/^START=A$/,/^END$/ { if ($0 != "START=A" && $0 != "END") print }'` (same basic idea, though you can code the condition in a number of different ways if desired)

Answer (score 4):

Basic version ...

```
sed -n '/START=A/,/END/p' yourfile
```

More robust version...

```
sed -n '/^ *START=A *$/,/^ *END *$/p' yourfile
```

Comment: can you explain what `,` means in sed pattern string?

Comment: @Vikrant - the `,` separates two parts of a *range* defined by two regexes so that the lines between the first pattern and the second pattern are returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` expression has a space before end, i.e `/ ^END/`. So `sed` gets the starting pattern, but does not get the ending pattern and keeps on printing till end. Use `sed '/^START=A/, /^END/!d' input_file` (notice `/^END/`)

Comment: Good point about the space in the `sed` regex, though it makes the quoted output even more puzzling (as in 'I cannot reproduce the quoted output with the original script, but drop the extraneous space and it works fine, albeit cackhanded').  You can at least simplify the last part of your `awk` script to `/END/{flag=0}` which might set flag to zero when it was already zero, but that does no harm.  You can also use `/START=A/,/END/{print}` which is much simpler.

Comment: yea, `/START=A/,/END/{print}` this is much simpler, but it's already shown in your answer :) I was just playing around with a flag :). Actually, after the `awk` solution you have given, he does not need to do anything else. I'll remove my `awk` solution. It might lead to more confusion than doing any good :P