# How to use grep,awk or sed to extract text between two strings?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Please help me in using either SED, AWK, or GREP to extract the following text. I have files that look similar to this.

```
Text text text text text text text
Text text text text text text text
   Table A
<TABLE>
xxx xxx xxx xxx
xxx xxx xxx xxx
</TABLE>
Text text text text text text text
Text text text text text text text
   Table B
<TABLE>
xxx xxx xxx xxx
xxx xxx xxx xxx
</TABLE>
```

I need all of the info for only table A but am not sure how to go about doing so.

Comment: what id the distinguishing part of `Table A`, what is the actual content?

Comment: replace all the text, text, text placeholders with actual, truly representative sample text. Add the expected output given that input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed to extract text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643288/sed-to-extract-text-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these may be what you want, depending on what your expected output and the rest of your text looks like:

```
$ awk '/Table A/{f=1} f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit}' file
   Table A
<TABLE>
xxx xxx xxx xxx
xxx xxx xxx xxx
</TABLE>

$ awk 'f{print; if (/<\/TABLE>/) exit} /Table A/{f=1}' file
<TABLE>
xxx xxx xxx xxx
xxx xxx xxx xxx
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no </TABLE> inside the TABLE element.

```
sed -n '/Table A/,/<\/TABLE>/p' | grep -v "Table A"
```

PS: the grep -v is probably not necessary I just do not know off the top of my head the option to not include the starting pattern.

That will print out

```
 <TABLE>
  xxx xxx xxx xxx
  xxx xxx xxx xxx
 </TABLE>
```

If you need the Text part this will not work. AWK would probably be better.

If you need something with a variable name you can do

```
 myTableName="Table A"
 sed -n "/${myTableName}/,/<\/TABLE>/p" | grep -v ${myTableName}
```

Comment: Don't do that. Ranges make trivial tasks very slightly briefer but then require duplicated conditions (as shown above) or complete rewrites given the tiniest requirements change. Just use a flag instead of a range (which means you should use awk, not sed and/or grep).

Answer (score 0):

You even can you `grep` for that, but awk seems like better.

`grep -A1000 "Table A" file.txt | grep -B1000 "Table B"`